# вопрос про метод sort() JS

Tags: javascript, сортировка

Почему при выводе в консоль переменные a и b меняются местами, хотя логично же, что a == первый элемент в массиве, а b == второй элемент. Или это не так?

```
const numbers = [67, 34, 124, 2, 54];

numbers.sort((a, b) => console.log(a, b));
```

в консоль выводит:

```
34 67
124 34
2 124
54 2
```

Разве не должен выводить:

```
67 34
34 124
124 2
2 54
```

Comment: Firefox выводит именно как «должен»

Comment: @andreymal вот он хитрый лис... :D

Comment: вывожу в консоль VS code) хотя в дев тулз хрома так же выводит

Comment: `= (5) [67, 34, 124, 2, 54]` консоль браузера опера по вашему коду) в чем проблема?(

Comment: @Jour вы не поняли вопрос))  вопрос не в том как сортируется

Comment: Нигде а стандарте не написано в каком порядке должны передаваться элементы в функцию сортировки.

Comment: @AlexeyTen но в таком случае и результаты будут разными в зависимости от того, что передается в переменную **a**, или я ошибаюсь?
`numbers.sort((a, b) => a > b ? 1 : -1)`

Comment: @IgorMokhov браузеры могут по разному реализовывать свои логики, главное, чтобы итог был равен тому, что указано в спецификации и документации

Comment: @IgorMokhov, будут, потому что ваша функция неправильная. Она не возвращает 0 для равных элементов.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский С браузерами  понятно, выполняю код в node.js и vscod + плагин code runner, результат тот же. Видимо он интерпретирует так же.

Comment: @IgorMokhov  может там просто эмуляция браузера

Comment: @AlexeyTen согласен, функцию нужно дописать…

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да, возможно

Comment: Ну вот, если функцию написать правильно, то будет неважно в каком порядке в неё приходят элементы.